# Make deepEquals(a, b) function without ===

Tags: javascript

How can I make function  **deepEquals(a, b)** for comparing two values without using === ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=== compares for Type AND Value, == compares Value

```
function deepEquals (a, b){
  if(typeof(a) == typeof(b) && a == b){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

But I can't imagine any Scenario where you could need this,